# How to generate numbers from an autocorrelated bivariate distribuition in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-testing, autocorrelation

My goal is to generate a bivariate distribuition with autocorrelation between the values in R, in order to simulate some statistic.

I've already been able to generate a bivariate distribuition using rmvnorm and an autocorrelated manually, where Xt[k] = mu*(1-fi) + fi*Xt[k-1] + sig*Et, but I can't generate a distribuition that envolves both concepts. Anyone have an idea?

For the bivariate distribuition, I used:

```
m = c(mean1, mean2) #mean vector
sig = matrix(c(vr1^2, cov, cov, vr2^2), nrow = 2) #covariance matrix 
DNB = rmvnorm(n, mean = m, sigma = sig)
```

Answer (score 1):

The portes package provides the varima.sim() function, which may work for you?

Having created your bivariate series DNB, you can use them as innovations in a VAR(1) model with k = 2 variables:

```
library(portes)
x <- varima.sim(model=list(ar=array(c(0.1,0.9,0.9,0.1),dim=c(2,2,1))), n = N, k = 2, innov = DNB)
```

where I created a phi matrix for the autoregressive part.

You can include a constant term in the above by using the constant parameter in the varima.sim() function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The thing I think I don't get here is the ar list, what exactly does it represent in this case?

Comment: In this instance, each component (k = 1,2) depends on the lagged values of itself and the other component. The ar list provides the corresponding coefficients.

Comment: what function should I use to get the ar list?